# Motivation behind the Archimedean norm on number fields .

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

It is easy to justify the use of non-archimedean norms on number fields from an "inside view" as arising from the prime ideals and are therefore clearly useful a priori.

However, it seems to me that the archimedean norms only make sense if one looks at the embedding of number fields inside $\Bbb C$ but there is no reason to consider this embedding before constructing the norm since $\Bbb C$ is defined as the closure under this norm.

One possible justification would be that there is precisely one archimedean norm on $\Bbb Q$ and this would be satisfactory if one could explain why the axioms we use for a norm should be a priori important in the context of number theory.

My question might be a little unclear and I will be happy to provide clarifications. I am basically looking for a reason why distances should matter in number theory. It is easy to see why we care about them in plane geometry and by extension analysis but they are also very useful in number theory and I do not see why they are useful a priori.

Comment: See Van der Waarden Book Algebra Vol 2. There we see this type of norms are realy about order of zeros on places of Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Wait until you reach the proof of the Minkowski bound, Dirichlet's theorem on units and the like. All the archimedean norms come into play simultaneously, or, more accurately, all those complex embeddings become important (together).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is actually partly why I am asking the question. I do not understand at all why the "trick" used in embedding everything into the lattice helps at all and why complex embeddings are so useful. I would like some more general framework(more so than just the concept of a norm) that explains the importance of all this.

Comment: You have surely seen distance used when proving that e.g. $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain. Some proofs of the law of quadratic reciprocity use $-(p-1)/2,-(p-3)/2,\ldots,1,2,\ldots,(p-1)/2$ as a preferred set of representatives modulo $p$ and their signs. Are those arguments not geometric in some sense?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think the $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a ED is very similar to the proof of Minkowski's theorem. Like I said, I understand the proofs in the sense of following the logic - I simply have no idea why these specific geometric ideas make sense and are useful in number theory. I am sorry if I am not making much sense - I might just have to think about this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one 
motivation
 for considering Archimedean valuations on an ''equal'' level with the non-Archimedean ones, from a purely arithmetic viewpoint.
When you do this, you get nice results like the following product formula:

$$ \text{for }x\in \mathbb{Q},\qquad \prod_v |x|_v = |x|_\infty\prod_p |x|_p = 1.$$
The first product is taken over all ''places'' $v$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, where place  means equivalence class of absolute values (choosing appropriate normalization), and the second product above uses Ostrowski's result that $\mathbb Q$ has a single Archimedean place, denoted $|x|_\infty$, and that all other places are the non-Archimedean ones corresponding to prime integers.

One way to interpret this product formula is that you actually *don't* need embeddings into $\mathbb C$ to figure out the Archimedean norm on $\mathbb Q$ -- you just have to multiply together all the non-Archimedean norms, and then take the reciprocal. The ''inside'' and ''outside'' views actually mirror each other.

For number fields $K$ of higher degree, 
the product formula $\prod_{v\in K} |x|_v = 1$ still holds, but since
you generally have more than one Archimedean norm (sometimes denoted $v|\infty$) this does not allow you to express a single Archimedean norm in terms of the non-Archimedean ones. However, it is still true that taken together, the product over non-Archimedean norms gives you equivalent information (that is, the multiplicative inverse) to the product over Archimedean norms.

---

You can think of this situation as closely analogous to the case of rational functions $k(T)$ over some algebraically closed ground field $k$. 
Assuming $k$ itself has no ''interesting'' norms, just the trivial one, then there are two types of norms on $k(T)$:

- the finite valuations $v_a((T-a)^n) = n$ for any $a\in k$
- the degree valuation $v_\infty(f(T)) = - \deg(f)$ for any polynomial $f\in k[T]$.

  (Here the valuations correspond to norms via $|\cdot| = \exp(-v(\cdot))$.)

Note that the finite valuation $v_a$ has the geometric interpretation of picking out the order of vanishing, as a zero or pole, of some function on the affine line $\mathbb A^1$, at the closed point $\mathfrak m_a = (T-a)$.
We  chose to denote the degree valuation by $v_\infty$ because there is also a perfectly nice geometric interpretation here:  if we consider the projective line $\mathbb P^1$ as containing $\mathbb A^1$ and one additional point $\infty$, then 
$v_\infty = -\deg$ picks out the order of vanishing of a function on $\mathbb P^1$ at $\infty$,
under the identification of $k(T)$ as the rational function field of both $\mathbb P^1$ and $\mathbb A^1$.

Given a rational function $f\in k(T)$, summing the orders of zeros and poles of $f$ over all points in $\mathbb A^1$ could give you any integer (e.g. when $f = T^n$). However, if we take the same sum over all points in the compact curve $\mathbb P^1$, then the sum is always $0$.
This corresponds to the product formula for $K = k(T)$:
$$ \sum_{v\in k(T)} v(f) = 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow\quad 
\prod_{v\in k(T)} |f|_v = 1.$$

---

The ''geometric'' case $K = k(T)$ has one important advantage over the ''arithmetic'' one $K = \mathbb Q$. 
In $k(T)$, the infinite valuation $v_\infty$ is isomorphic to any of the finite ones $v_a$ in the sense that there is an automorphism of $k(T)$ sending one to the other, namely $T-a \mapsto \frac1{T-a}$.
In $\mathbb Q$, however, there is no such automorphism which exchanges $v_\infty$ with any $v_p$, since $v_p$ is a discrete valuation while $v_\infty$ is not.
The geometric analogy suggests that by considering the Archimedean (or ''infinite'') place $v_\infty \in \mathbb Q$ in addition to the $p$-adic places, we are somehow compactifying an arithmetic curve. But the resulting compactification is not smooth and homogeneous like $\mathbb P^1$; rather, the arithmetic curve is highly singular at $\infty$.

Comment: You probably dropped the assumption that $ k $ is algebraically closed somewhere; otherwise $ k[X] $ has maximal ideals which are not of the form you describe, which give rise to prime valuations in much the same way.

Comment: yes, thanks for catching that! I was worried that this would break the analogy with $\mathbb Q$ since it is not algebraically closed, but neither is $k(T)$. It's also possible to describe the prime valuations of $k(T)$ in general in terms of Galois orbits over $k^{alg}$, but I think the better analogy is with the algebraically closed case.